# Proof by contradiction vs contrapositive

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations, solution-verification

I recently did a proof using the contrapositive. I know that the contrapositive is similar to proof by contradiction however, as a newbie to proofs, I was wondering where the difference lies? In particular, using the example attempt below, how would one go about a proof by contradiction (assuming there is one)?

Suppose $T : V\rightarrow{W}$ is a linear transformation between finite-dimensional vector spaces and that $\dim (V) > \dim (W)$. Prove that $T$ is not injective.

Proof.

Assume that $T: V\rightarrow{W}$ is injective and let $B = \{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$, where $\dim(V) = n$. Since $v_1, ..., v_n$ are linearly independent,

$$a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n = 0 \implies a_1 = ... = a_n = 0$$

Suppose $b_1w_1 + ... + b_nw_n = 0$, where $w_i\in{W}$ s.t. $T(v_i) = w_i$ for $i = 1, ..., n$.

Then,

$$b_1T(v_1) + ... + b_nT(v_n) = 0$$

$$\implies T(b_1w_1 + ... + b_nw_n) = 0$$

$$\implies b_1 = ... = b_n = 0$$ from the linear independence of $v_1, ..., v_n$

So, $W$ contains at least n linearly independent vectors. Thus,

$$\dim(V) = n \leq{\dim(W)}$$

As a result, $T$ is injective $\implies \dim(V) \leq{\dim(W)}$.

By the contrapositive, $NOT(\dim(V)\leq{\dim(W)}) \implies NOT(T$ is injective).

Therefore, $\dim(W)>\dim(V) \implies T$ is not injective.

QED.

First of all, is my proof above correct? I hope it is...

Now, using contradiction, would I assume that $T$ is injective and $\dim(V) > \dim(W)$ and from the result above that $\dim(V) = n \leq{\dim(W)}$, I can conclude a contradiction?

Any explanations and alternative examples, as usual, are much appreciated.

Comment: If I want to prove "if A then B", then I can either prove it directly, or prove the contrapositive - "if not B then not A". If I wanted to prove this by contradiction, I would say "If not B, then <blah blah> and so not A, but this contradicts A". The first part, "if not B ... then not A" is essentially the contrapositive statement. I suppose what differentiates contraposition from contradiction is their approach - in contraposition, to prove that "All apples are fruit" I simply prove that "If something is not a fruit then it is not an apple". I make no assumptions about...

Comment: ... the initial conditions. On the other hand, for a contradiction I would say "Let this object be an apple, but assume it is not a fruit. Then..." and somehow derive that it cannot be an apple, contradicting my initial assumption. They're closely related, but not entirely the same.

Comment: Your examples are correct in saying whether they are by contrapositive or contradiction. Many times a proof by contradiction can be rewritten in contrapositive form, and sometimes in 'direct' form.

Comment: @nhmwhhxx That makes sense! So the fundamental difference is, given the proposition $p \implies q$, the initial assumption of $p$ and not $q$ instead of just not $q$.

Comment: Here's something that happens in practice. One begins a proof of $P \implies Q$ by assuming $Q$ is false, and then one follows one's nose, unsure whether one is doing a proof by contrapositive or a proof by contradiction. Sometimes one ends up directly proving $P$ is false; et voila, proof by contrapositive. Othertimes, some way down the road, one ends up applying the assumption that $P$ is true and then, further down the road, one reaches an absurd conclusion like $0=1$; et voila, proof by contradiction.

Comment: @TRONIIX Yep pretty much. If you're familiar with formal logic, a proof by contrapositive goes $\lnot q \implies \lnot p$, whereas a contradiction goes $ \lnot q \land p \implies \bot$.